# Apache crashing with seg fault on a graceful restart on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: amazon-ec2, ubuntu-14.04, php-7, apache2.4

One of the servers I manage runs `Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS` with `Apache 2.4.7` and `PHP 7.0.11` , and uses `PHP's Zend OPcache v7.0.11`. It is noted that apache went down every time when we ran the `service apache2 graceful` (service apache2 reload) command. Apache error log showing the following.

```
[mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 9662] AH00171: Graceful restart requested, doing restart
*** Error in `/usr/sbin/apache2': corrupted double-linked list: 0x00007f9e1ae8a170 ***
[core:notice] [pid 9662] AH00060: seg fault or similar nasty error detected in the parent process
```

Apache configuration

```
#apachectl -V
Server version: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   Jul 15 2016 15:34:04 
Server's Module Magic Number: 20120211:27  
Server loaded:  APR 1.5.1-dev, APR-UTIL 1.5.3  
Compiled using: APR 1.5.1-dev, APR-UTIL 1.5.3  
Architecture:   64-bit  
Server MPM:     prefork  
  threaded:     no  
    forked:     yes (variable process count)  
Server compiled with....  
 -D APR_HAS_SENDFILE  
 -D APR_HAS_MMAP  
 -D APR_HAVE_IPV6 (IPv4-mapped addresses enabled)  
 -D APR_USE_SYSVSEM_SERIALIZE  
 -D APR_USE_PTHREAD_SERIALIZE  
 -D SINGLE_LISTEN_UNSERIALIZED_ACCEPT  
 -D APR_HAS_OTHER_CHILD  
 -D AP_HAVE_RELIABLE_PIPED_LOGS  
 -D DYNAMIC_MODULE_LIMIT=256  
 -D HTTPD_ROOT="/etc/apache2"  
 -D SUEXEC_BIN="/usr/lib/apache2/suexec"  
 -D DEFAULT_PIDLOG="/var/run/apache2.pid"  
 -D DEFAULT_SCOREBOARD="logs/apache_runtime_status"  
 -D DEFAULT_ERRORLOG="logs/error_log"  
 -D AP_TYPES_CONFIG_FILE="mime.types"  
 -D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="apache2.conf"
```

After some amount of searching on the Internet, the only thing I could come up with that there were some Apache modules might be causing this issue. One of the posts indicated that this particular message is also a symptom for lots of other memory-type bugs in Apache. **After disabling the php7.0** module the issue resolved

However anyone can help me to fix this issue without disabling the apache php module ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: what's your php modules you use ? and don't list your module via cli , try to get your php/apache modules :)

Comment: Php Modules
apache2ctl -M

Comment: i mean your php/apache modules , check out , [get_loaded_extensions](http://php.net/get-loaded-extensions) .

Comment: @HassanAhmed
Please see the loaded modules.
====
Core  
date  
libxml  
openssl  
pcre  
zlib  
filter  
hash  
pcntl  
Reflection  
SPL  
session  
standard  
mysqlnd  
PDO  
cassandra  
xml  
calendar  
ctype  
curl  
dom  
exif  
fileinfo  
ftp  
gettext  
iconv  
imagick  
json  
mysqli  
pdo_mysql  
Phar  
posix  
propro  
raphf  
readline  
shmop  
SimpleXML  
sockets  
sysvmsg  
sysvsem  
sysvshm  
tokenizer  
wddx  
xmlreader  
xmlwriter  
xsl  
http  
Zend